# Blink LED on New Twitter Follower

Tags: c, arduino, httprequest

I'm working on a small Arduino project that would make an LED light blink when a new follower is gained. Obviously I'm limited by some of Twitter's rules in this respect (# of requests from their server, etc.) but I've found a way to potentially make it work.

I have a PHP script that checks the number of followers I have. The first time the script is run, if no file exists, it creates a text file with the number of followers as the only contents of the file. If I have 42 followers, then the file will contain `42` and nothing else. On subsequent runs, the script checks if the contents of the file match the new follower count. If it does, it does nothing to the file and outputs an `n`. If the number doesn't match (meaning I've gained a new follower), then I update the text file and output `y`.

On the Arduino side, I'm simply checking if the output of the script page contains `y` or `n`, with the intent that the former causes my LED to blink.

Two issues I'm running into:

Usually, when I read from the script file itself, in the case of a response of `n`, I'm getting output like:

```
1
n
0
```

This is strange, where are the 1 and 0 coming from? They're not visible in the page output itself. I've gone as far as setting the encoding type to `plain/text` as well. When I read from a regular text file, I get only the contents of the file (in this case, it would be `n`).

The other problem I'm facing is that sometimes, instead of getting the above output, I get the entire HTTP response. That is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 24 Dec 2013 04:03:32 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By
```

Mind you, it stops there in my output because I have code checking for `y`. This is obviously flawed, but I'd hoped to expand upon it as soon as I could fix the first issue. That being said, why does it sometimes give me the entire HTTP response like this?

So the question is: is there something wrong with my code that's causing this? If so, how can I modify it to better read an HTTP response for what I like?

This would be a useless question without the code, so here it is (without the internet login info of course ... I've also linked it here - [CODE](http://raw-d.com/private/sampleQuestion.c)):

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Twitter.h>

int led = 13;

char ssid[] = ""; //  your network SSID (name) 
char pass[] = "";    // your network password (use for WPA, or use as key for WEP)

int keyIndex = 0;            // your network key Index number (needed only for WEP)

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS; // status of the wifi connection

// initialize the library instance:
WiFiClient client;

const unsigned long requestInterval = 30*1000;    // delay between requests; 30 seconds

// if you don't want to use DNS (and reduce your sketch size)
// use the numeric IP instead of the name for the server:
//IPAddress server(199,59,149,200);    // numeric IP for api.twitter.com
char server[] = "raw-d.com";     // name address for twitter API

boolean requested;                     // whether you've made a request since connecting
unsigned long lastAttemptTime = 0;     // last time you connected to the server, in milliseconds

String currentLine = "";               // string to hold the text from server
String tweet = "";                     // string to hold the tweet
boolean readingTweet = false;          // if you're currently reading the tweet

String lastCount = ""; //last number counted

int numberOfBytes=0;

char* textFound;


void setup()
{
  // reserve space for the strings:
  currentLine.reserve(256);
  tweet.reserve(150);
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  // check for the presence of the shield:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("WiFi shield not present"); 
    // don't continue:
    while(true);
  } 

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:    
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  } 
  // you're connected now, so print out the status: (or not)
  //printWifiStatus();
//  connectToServer();
}

void loop()
{
  //connectToServer();
  //delay(10000);
  if (client.connected())
  {
    Serial.println("Connected. Checking for availabiilty of client...");
    if (client.available())
    {
      Serial.println("Client is available! Trying to read from client...");
      // read incoming bytes:

      if(client.find("\r\n\r\n"))
      {
      char inChar;

      while(inChar=client.read())
      {
        if(inChar==-1) break;
        currentLine+=inChar; //read in all characters of count
        Serial.print("\n\nCurrent follower count: " + currentLine + "\n\n");
        if(inChar=='y' || inChar == 'n') break;
      }
      if(inChar=='y')
      {
        //lastCount=currentLine;
        Serial.println("BLINKING LED");
        blink(); //blink LED
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.println("NOT BLINKING.");
      }
      currentLine=""; //clear
      delay(5000); //delay 5 seconds (don't kill server)
     }
     else
     {
       Serial.println("newlines not found - error with request");
     }
    }  
  }
  else if (millis() - lastAttemptTime > requestInterval)
  {
    // if you're not connected, and two minutes have passed since
    // your last connection, then attempt to connect again:
    connectToServer();
  }
}

void blink()
{
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(3000);               // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  //delay(1000);               // wait for a second
}

void connectToServer()
{
  // attempt to connect, and wait a millisecond:
  Serial.println("connecting to server...");
  if (client.connect(server, 80))
  {
    Serial.println("making HTTP request...");
    // make HTTP GET request to twitter:
    client.println("GET /private/followers.php HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host:raw-d.com");
    client.println("Connection:close");
    client.println();


  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Failure to connect.");
  }
  // note the time of this connect attempt:
  lastAttemptTime = millis();
}

void runPhpScript()
{
  // attempt to connect, and wait a millisecond:
  Serial.println("connecting to server...");
  if (client.connect(server, 80))
  {
    Serial.println("making HTTP request...");
    client.println("GET /private/followers.php HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host:raw-d.com");
    client.println("Connection:close");
    client.println();
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Failure to run script.");
  }
  // note the time of this connect attempt:
  lastAttemptTime = millis();
}


void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your problem, with the extra 1 and 0, that looks like it might be the HTTP chunked encoding, where the server sends the response in chunks that are prefixed by their length. If that is the case then there'll be a header like `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` in the response, which indicates that the client must decode the chunked encoding to get the raw payload. You can probably prevent the server from using chunked encoding by explicitly setting a Content-Length header in your PHP script:

```
header('Content-Length: 1');
```

With the information provided it's not 100% clear why you're intermittently seeing the HTTP header appear as the payload, but in general HTTP has a bunch of fiddly features that might be in play here. Since you control this server and it's tightly coupled to your Arduino project, a quick-and-dirty solution would be to change your signalling bytes to be values that you know will never occur in the HTTP header, like some byte values greater than 127. Full handling of chunked encoding and other HTTP features on the Arduino side is possible but probably isn't worth it for this application where you're already tailoring your server to the Arduino sketch anyway.